# Slashes instead of $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I know that this is a question that has been already answered. The trouble is that I don't know what I am doing wrong but when I paste in the code I found in the other:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
```

...nothing happens.

I simply expect the url to become like : www.foo.com/it/5
instead of www.foo.com?it=5

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please use google for such questions: https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=apache+mod+rewrite+nice+urls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=PKNxUYrTGIiwPLLsgdAE#safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=nIy&channel=fs&q=apache+mod_rewrite+nice+urls&spell=1&sa=X&ei=PKNxUcyaJMSsPeeYgfgJ&ved=0CDEQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45373924,d.ZWU&fp=95efa6a10eabc125&biw=1280&bih=569

Comment: Have you ever heard about `Routing mechanism`?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't rewrite the URL that *you* see, it rewrites the rule that *Apache* sees.

Also, those rules are ridiculous. I suggest something simpler like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  #skip if file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  #skip if directory exists
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The when someone requests:

```
http://foo.com/fancy/url/here
```

Apache changes it [internally] to:

```
http://foo.com/index.php?rt=fancy/url/here
```

your PHP script sees:

```
$_GET['rt'] == 'fancy/url/here';
```

and then you can:

```
$arr = explode('/', $_GET['rt']);
```

to get:

```
$arr == array('fancy','url','here')
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but those rules return an error: /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters